# Using \def to pass options to axis environment in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to pass label descriptions into a pgfplot by utilizing the `\def` macro right before entering the `tikzpicture` environment.

The following code works as intended:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \def\labels{xlabel=x, ylabel=y}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[\labels]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to render the x-label italic. Using the `\textit{}` command inside the `axis` environment works as well:

```
...
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=y]
    \end{axis}
...
```

[image]

However I run into issues when I utilize the `\textit{}` command in the definition, resulting in no compilation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \def\labels{xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=y}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[\labels]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Do you know into which issue I'm falling here? I guess it has something to do with scoping but wasn't able to find a solution yet.

Surely I'm not looking for the solution to render the x-label italic but rather on how to pass in such options to an axis from outside the tikzpicture environment.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! You can achieve all this easily with pgf keys. (I added a plot just to avoid having an empty axis. Note also that for more advanced tasks it is worthwhile to set the compatibility to the newest version, which currently is `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`. Also it is "more correct" to set the corresponding font to `\itshape` but this is all to show that your intended outcome works *with pgf keys*.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \pgfplotsset{my labels/.style={xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=y}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[my labels]
    \addplot{x};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi marmot, thank you. Using keys for this feels solid.

Comment: @Alexander You're welcome! The main concept of pgfplots is pgf keys, hence its name.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution to this kind of problem is to write macros that, when expanded, produce exactly the markup you would have written by hand. This way, the command behind `\begin{axis}` can't complain since it will see nothing else than `xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=\textit{y}` in its optional argument (there is no user macro to expand). LaTeX2e version:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand*{\mypicture}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=\textit{#1}, ylabel=\textit{#2}]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  \mypicture{x}{y}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX3 version of the same (can be useful for more complicated things, because LaTeX3 is great to allow you to control when and how things are expanded—as well as to define macros featuring a starred variant, macros with one or several optional arguments in various places, etc.):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \alex_create_pic:nn #1#2
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[xlabel=\textit{#1}, ylabel=\textit{#2}]
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \mypicture { m m }
  {
    \alex_create_pic:nn {#1} {#2}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \mypicture{x}{y}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi frougon, thank you this explains A LOT! I'll work with marmot's proposition but your comment is definitely helping me to understand what went wrong.